# matplotlib: fill_between function, how to 'Interpolate' and 'where' correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The length of value arrays for my line chart with matplotlib could be irregular, for example:

```
[18,17,0,0,2]
[6,4,0,0]
[3]
```

These are values on a time line, the last being the latest, every value corresponding to a week. Thus this means the second user joined a week later than the first, and the last only joined the last week.

In order to draw a line chart, I fill the smaller arrays with None values (not really relevant to `fill_between`).

```
[18, 17, 0, 0, 2]
[None, None, None, None, 3]
[None, 6, 4, 0, 0]
```

I am using `interpolate=True` because, I need to fill the curve if values go to zero.
However, this has the unintended effect that for people starting later, the filling will also interpolate, starting from 0 to the actual value. 
[image: fill_between how it looks like now]

I need it to only fill the space if there are actual values:
[image: should be]

Can this be done? I looked at the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) and it says something about the where array.

Here's the structure of my where array for this given chart:

```
[True, True, False, False, True, False]
[False, True, True, False, False, False]
[False, False, False, False, True, False]
```

As you can see I set the first where element to be False for the second value row, but because of "`interpolate=True`, it will start filling...

(Color codes: first row blue, second row green, third red)

Hope any angel can help on this....

Here's the actual code for the fill:

```
for i, values in enumerate(time_series):
    ax.plot(x, y[i], ',-', label=label, color=linecolor, markersize=8, fillstyle="full",linewidth=1.5, clip_on=True, zorder=200)
    ax.fill_between(x, 0, zero_y, where=where, color=fillcolors[i], alpha=0.8, edgecolor="white", zorder=zorder[i], interpolate=True)
```

Take note that `fill_between` actually crashed when fed with `None` values...I need to "translate" `None` values to 0...which is further complicating issues maybe...

Comment: try relpacing `None` with `np.nan` which is the float 'not a number' fill value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally mpl converts your lists to `np.ndarray`.  The proper value for 'not a number' (which can be used for missing data) is `np.nan`.  Replacing all of the `None` with `np.nan` will fix the problem.